# Use pkg-config with Homebrew installed software

Tags: homebrew, pkg, library

I have installed some libraries with Homebrew but if I use pkg-config it does not find them because there are missing .pc files.

For example, if you do:

```
brew install opencv
```

and, after it is installed:

```
pkg-config --libs opencv
```

I get this error:

```
Package opencv was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `opencv.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'opencv' found
```

This error is caused because Homebrew does not create any `opencv.pc`.

Is there a way to configure Homebrew to create the .pc files so that all packages installed with brew can be found by pkg-config?

Answer (score 6):

Check with `brew ls opencv` that there is no `opencv.pc` installed.  I tried it and I have one.  If you don't get one, then there is a bug in the package.

Otherwise, check that you are using the correct Homebrew `pkg-config`.  Check with `which pkg-config` and `ls -l $(which pkg-config)` where it is coming from.

Comment: Thanks! this led me to report a bug in the `webkitgkt` package.

Answer (score 0):

This post fixed it for me. It explains how to set a missing environment variable for `pkg-config` that points to all the installed packages.

https://prateekvjoshi.com/2013/10/18/package-opencv-not-found-lets-find-it/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.